# Memory garbage pj_str struct

Tags: c++, pjsip

After allocating and initializing a `char*` and copying a data for it

```
char * uri= new char [strlen(realm) + strlen("sip:") +1]();
strcpy(uri, "sip:"); 
strcat(uri, realm);
```

I pass this `char*` to `pj_str(char*)` function. This function convert the `char*` to `pj_str_t` `struct` that contains a pointer to the buffer and its length.

Then the function continue its logic and uses the `uri pj_str`.

Before the function return, it's supposed to deallocate `*uri`. When doing this line of code the first two characters contain an octal garbage data else it contains the expected data.

```
delete [] uri;
```

What is the problem?!

Comment: Does `delete` fail somehow? If not, I am not sure what you are complaining about - you shouldn't look at `uri` after `delete`. Also, can you show the line where you call `pj_str`?

Comment: Are you deleting the array when it is pointed to else where?

Comment: Did you really `strcpy` and `strcat` into two separate variables? uri and authUri?

Comment: @mtrw Neil Kirk
Thanks guys, I have figured out the problem. There is another process that uses the uri ptr.

Comment: @mtrw Even if i delete the uri ptr then accessing it, it returns me the whole string except the first two characters are garbage ?
How come!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't it enough to do

```
delete [] uri;
```

Comment: Yes it is enough but, the problem is when executing this line. The first two characters of uri pj_str that i have processed are an octal garbage data.

Comment: Can you show the code of your function? maybe its a Shallow Copy?

Comment: No, I have figured out the problem. There is another variable that uses the uri ptr. Thanks